# How to communicate with Components through angular 2 router

Tags: angular

I have following things:

```
<app-scrollable-area (scrolledDown)="..." class="scrollable-y">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-scrollable-area>
```

the Question is how should i tell inside components about this event? `(scrolledDown)`
Maybe i should implement general service for aggregating events?

Before, i used local variables but when i integrated routing then the situation changed.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: it's turned out all necessary information is alredy on official docs: [Communicating via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#bidirectional-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scroll service:

```
export class ScrollService {
   subject: Subject;
   constructor() {
      this.subject = new Subject();
   }
   setScroll(newY: number) {
      this.subject.next(number);
   }

   registerScroll(): Observable<number> {
      return this.subject.asObservable();
   }
}
```

You need to inject this service wherever you need it.
By `setScroll()` you emit the new scroll to all subscribers.
Every consumer can subscribe to `registerScroll()` and do work when emits.

Comment: thank you @Avi! what is difference between using `Subject` and using `EventEmitter` ?

Comment: Good question, EventEmitter extends Subject. Used by directives and components to emit custom Events.